# HP ProBook 4540s is overheating while using Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, drivers, hp

I'm using dual boot with Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04. When I use Windows 8, everything works perfectly but when I use Ubuntu 12.04 my CPU heats up too quickly.

Why does it happen only in Ubuntu and not in windows and what can I do to prevent it.

Thanks!

My computer: HP ProBook 4540s

Comment: Many friends of mine have the same issue. I guess Ubuntu doesn't have a power management system like windows does,

Comment: It does and its actually part of the kernel for a long time. Mostly these are issues caused by the graphics GPU and not the CPU and that is managed by the display driver in use.

Comment: Can you feel the heat or is it just the fans are on? I ask because I have a Probook 4510s and it's fan are always on full after I wake the computer from sleep, it's a known bug and has been around for ages. theres a bug report here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-source-2.6.17/+bug/77370

Comment: is there any way so i can switch between graphics cards like i can tell in Windows on what application I need AMD Radeon HD and on what i dont ?

Answer (score 3):

### Install your display driver....

I have the same laptop with AMD Radeon HD 7650M 1GB VGA. Go to the *System Settings> Additional Drivers*, and install the graphics diver, if you are using AMD hardware like me.

This should work also if you have a Nvidia card.

Comment: Indeed there is a driver, but when I install it I won't be able to use GNOME3 full \ Unity 3D..

Comment: I have instlled the drivers and still i am having the problem of over heating. From where I switch between graphics cards ?

Answer (score 3):

Turning off switchable graphics in BIOS should make your laptop run cooler and double the battery life.

Comment: how can one turn off switchable graphics from BIOS? what are the steps?

Comment: There is an option in "Integrated Hardware" > Discrete Video Card

Answer (score 0):

It's not just the CPU, the main cause it's the GPU, because this laptop has a integrated intel HD graphics 4000 if i'm not mistaken and the dedicated one radeon 7XXX HD depending on model. The thing is, when running on Windows 8 ,or Windows in general , it happens that in low - medium demanding processes, it runs on the integrated one, which is not weak at all, but it runs on it for generating less heat to the whole system. When running higher demanding processes such as top notch games, it switch to the more powerful one , the Radeon. The thing is that on Ubuntu, this doesn't happen. BOTH of the GPU's are running, overall generating more heat to the whole machine. This is the cause for overheating on ubuntu, as i'm not a master ubuntu user, i don't know exact coordonation for solving the problem, but this is what happens, i hope i cleared the situation for you a bit. Cheers !

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer. You could summarize and add it as a comment.